# VBScript- Single line as administrator

Tags: windows, vbscript, administrator

Is it possible to use the shell.run command to run the specified program as an administrator?

for instance:

```
shell.run(cmd.exe) <---Run this as admin
shell.run(Notepad) <---Run this as normal
```

I know i can execute the script to run as admin but that means everything inside that script is executed as an administrator.

My other option was to seperate the scripts and run one as admin and include what needs to be ran as admin in that script, then call another script to run and run that one as normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", , , "runas", 1
oShell.Run "notepad.exe"
```

(Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/ITCG/thread/310e57f9-2367-4293-9f97-53d0e077aacc)

(More Info: http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html)

Comment: nodepad.exe should probably read notepad.exe

Comment: Thanks @AndrewDennison; good spot after 11 years unnoticed

Answer (score 0):

Windows (from XP through to Win7 at least) has a `runas` command which does what you need. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) for details.

So, instead of running `cmd.exe`, you would run `runas.exe`, giving `cmd.exe` as the program to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Dim ObjShell
Set ObjShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell.Run "runas /K (command goes here) "
ObjShell.Run "notepad.exe"
```