# How do I get write permissions in the home folder (or the appdata folder, for windows) in Java?

Tags: java, permissions, io

I am trying to save some user settings in the home/appdata folder, but when I use dir.canwrite() it returns false. This is the code I use to determine the home/appdata folder:

```
public static String getAppDataPath() {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        return System.getenv("APPDATA");
    } else {
        return getUnixHome();
    }
}

public static String getUnixHome() {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    return home != null ? home : "~";
}
```

And this is the code trying to mkdir:

```
public static boolean checkExistenceDir(String path) {
    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
}
```

The path in question is:

```
getAppDataPath() + ".foo" + File.separatorChar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Java process to be started as an Administrator.

[You can create a run.vbs script in Windows to start your jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060215/vbscript-single-line-as-administrator):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", , , "runas", 1
oShell.Run "java -jar myjar.jar"
```

To make the program always run as administrator, you need it to run as administrator at least once and update a registry key.

Comment: Each time? I know java applications (Minecraft, for example) that don't start in it and they get the job done. What's the difference here?

Comment: @EvertVP - presumably, Minecraft is launched by a script or a custom launcher that does the equivalent to the above.  But the point is, you can't do it in pure Java.