# Reading,Writing to external xml file from JAR

Tags: java, xml, file-io, jar

I've been searching through stack overflow and tried multiply answers,
The thing about my problem is that if I try the program from my IDE (eclipse) then it works fine.
But when I create the JAR file, and try to run it from there it doesn't work at all.

So far I think it is something about how I define my file, what I find pretty weird cause I got it as solution to a similar question.

```
public class HighscoreXML {

private  String path = new File(Menu.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParentFile()+"/Highscore.xml";
private File file = new File(path);



public  ArrayList<Player> readXML(){
    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();      
    if (!file.exists()){
        try {
             createFile();  
        }catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        try{
            Document readDoc = builder.build(file);
            Element root = readDoc.getRootElement();

            for(Element element : root.getChildren("Player")){
                Player player = new Player("name", "0", "0");
                player.setName(element.getChildText("Name"));
                player.setScore(element.getChildText("Score"));
                player.setTime(element.getChildText("Time"));
                players.add(player);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return players;
}
      }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`? You can't write _into_ your jar file - it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Where do you want the file to go ???, for example System.getProperty("user.home") gets user home directory, you can also work out where the jar is located

Comment: I'm not trying to write inside my jar, that is what external means. I got that code from stack overflow and I tested it, it passes me the path to where my jar is located, not the path to my jar. So the raw path is correct ...

Comment: @BruceMartin , i want it tot work for mac and win

Comment: Creating a directory under  System.getProperty("user.home") is probably the simplest but there can be issues with that on Windows, see http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787931. The alternative is to use APPDATA on windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440993/how-do-i-get-write-permissions-in-the-home-folder-or-the-appdata-folder-for-wi for creating a directory under appdata