# Classic asp VB Wscript output

Tags: cmd, asp-classic, wscript.shell, qpdf

Thanks for reading  / helping.
On an old win2003 server, in this scenario:

```
Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
Dim shell, exec, strOutput

Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c echo hello world") ' << this line changes in each example

If exec.Status = WshFailed Then
    strOutput = exec.StdErr.ReadAll
Else
    strOutput = exec.StdOut.ReadAll
End If
response.write strOutput
```

I get the perfect response: "Helllo world", both in CMD and in ASP.
also with

```
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ping 127.0.0.1")
```

Again, perfect response, both in CMD and in ASP.

But I need to know how big a pdf is. So I tried 2 tools:

```
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c qpdf --show-npages c:\utils\b.pdf")
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c pdfinfo -v c:\utils\b.pdf")
```

Both work in cmd, it outputs what I want to know, but I get no response in asp.
Both tools have IUSR rights.
What am I missing?
Thanks a lot,

Alex

My comments below properly readable:

Good point. I forgot to mention that I did include in the system variables:

var:  pdfinfo   val: c:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\pdfinfo.exe

var:  qpdf      val: c:\WINDOWS\system32\qpdf.exe

relevant part of PATH:

%SystemRoot%\system32;

C:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\;

C:\utils\;

But, funny enough:

```
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c pdfinfo -meta c:\utils\b.pdf")
```

> CMD.exe starts, that's all. But, on your suggestion, I tried

```
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ""c:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\pdfinfo.exe"" -meta c:\utils\b.pdf")
```

as well: (sometimes, not all the time) Process Explorer shows pdfinfo being started up by cmd as well.
Still no response to ASP though.
Thank you for helping :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are `qpdf` and `pdfinfo` executables?  What happens if you fully-qualify the path to both and specify the file extensions?  My guess is that classic ASP might not be able to locate those files by searching the %PATH%.  For example, `Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF24\qpdf\bin\qpdf.exe"" --show-npages c:\utils\b.pdf")`

Comment: Good point.  
I forgot to mention that I did include in the system variables:  
var: pdfinfo  
val: c:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\pdfinfo.exe  
  
var: qpdf  
val: c:\WINDOWS\system32\qpdf.exe  
  
relevant part of PATH:  
  
%SystemRoot%\system32;    
C:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\;   
C:\utils\;

Comment: But, funny enough:  
 Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c pdfinfo -meta c:\utils\b.pdf")  
 > CMD.exe starts, that's all.  
But, on your suggestion, I tried  
 Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ""c:\Program Files\Utils\xpdf\pdfinfo.exe"" -meta c:\utils\b.pdf")  
 > and (sometimes, not all the time) Process Explorer shows pdfinfo being started up by cmd as well  
 
still no response though.

(sorry I cannot get the "2 spaces = line breaks" to work )  And thank you for helping :-)

Comment: Can you redirect standard output to a file, then read-in the contents of the file after the executables run?  For example, `Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF24\qpdf\bin\qpdf.exe"" --show-npages c:\utils\b.pdf > c:\utils\output.txt")`  Then, open  c:\utils\output.txt, read all its contents, and parse it.  This assumes there's content saved into c:\utils\output.txt after the executable runs.

Comment: Hi LeeHarvey, yes I assume that could be a workaround. One I was hoping to avoid, as a web application is all about speed :-). But maybe I can trick the user by presenting the info later on :-)

Comment: Try to redirect output as suggested above. If not working (i.e. no output.txt generated) it means asp/IIS process has no permissions to properly run qpdf.exe and you will need to fix permissions. Alternative try is to run as admin/poweruser, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060215/vbscript-single-line-as-administrator or https://superuser.com/questions/1171404/launch-a-bat-file-without-a-command-window-as-administrator

Answer (score 0):

The problem has finally been solved. Can't say for 100% certain what solved it, but for anyone reading this:
this code

```
Set exec = shell.Exec("cmd.exe /c qpdf --show-npages c:\utils\b.pdf")
```

was correct but not working. It started to work after I changed:

- qpdf.exe ( in system32) had full control on IUSR, qpdf13.dll did not. Changed.
- C:\utils\b.pdf had full control on IUSR, but the folder C:\utils did not. Changed the test to folder C:\test\ which did have Full Control on IUSR.
- restarted just in case.

Thank you for the help!